# Zero all the bits after the 2nd index

Tags: c, bit

i want to zero all the bits after the 2nd index (Including the 2nd) in an unsigned int. Here's the non working code i wrote so far: (temp is an unsigned int.)

```
for(int i=2; i< DSLength(dnaS); i++)
        {
            temp = temp & (0 << i);
        }
```

It keeps zeroing the whole number...

Comment: `0 << i` is equal to 0 !!

Comment: If you want to zero all bits except the lowest two, it's `x & 3`.

Comment: The correct way to clear bit `i` is `temp = temp & ~(1 << i)`, or `temp &= (1 << i)`. Try writing out the computations in binary to see what is happening.  Look at how `~(1 << i)` is different from `0 << i`.

Comment: To clear the n'th bit of number, you would use `number &= ~(1UL << n)` But, there's no need to do this one bit at a time, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correct, and you want to preserve the lowest two bits and zero all the rest, you don't need a loop:

```
x &= 3
```

does exactly that with `x`.